# Tengo problemas al instalar un script, no me reconoce el comando que me instala en ubuntu con WSL

Tags: linux, ubuntu, script, wsl

Hola amigos tengo problemas con un script que trato de instalar en mi ubuntu en WSL(windows), resulta que parecería que me instala el script que instala el comando pero al ejecutar el comando no se reconoce, me aparece este error:

```
Command 'dcli' not found, did you mean:
  command 'adcli' from deb adcli (0.9.1-1ubuntu2)
  command 'cli' from deb mono-runtime (6.8.0.105+dfsg-3.2)
Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

el comando se llama dcli, es un comando que en la empresa donde camello crearon y el problema es que mis demás compañeros no tuvieron problemas al instalarlo y lo pueden usar, pero en mi caso no es así :/, alguno sabe que podría estar pasando, les agradecería cualquier tipo de ayuda cracks

**Edit:** esto es lo que contiene el script install.sh:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ese archivo settings.py tiene una configuración para poder ingresar a unos dominios, unos perfiles y acceso a las regiones en aws y los buckets.... para agregar más el comando dcli se usa dentro de la empresa para facilitar el ingreso rápido a instancias y estados de microservicios. El script que configuraron aprovecha Python para ejecutar los diferentes comando con dli

Comment: cómo "crearon el comando" en la empresa"?

Comment: todo esto esta en un repositorio, entonces el script install.sh adentro tiene configurado para que ejecute un archivo que este dentro de ese mismo repositorio que se llama settings.py... voy a editar el post de arriba para agregar esta info amigo @Alfabravo..... lo raro es que en mi pc no me funciona y yo ya intente desinstalando ubuntu la versión 22.04 y volverla a instalar y nada

Comment: @Alfabravo ya edite mi pos con más info, alli coloque que contiene el archivo settings.py (no puedo agregar el codigo por temas de seguridad), pero la finalidad de ese install.sh es instalar el comando dcli, lo raro es que parece que soy el unico del equipo que no le instala en el pc :/